# How to print a number if it is non-zero and blank otherwise using printf?

Tags: c, printf, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I have the following function and it is giving some weird output if i value is 0
Could someone explain me why this is behaving weird ? My intention is to print the value only if it non-zero and otherwise it should be blank

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i=0;
    printf("Number is %d\n", i ? i : "");
    return 0;
}

-> gcc print.c
print.c: In function 'main':
print.c:5: warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
-> ./a.out
Number is 4195848
```

I know I can do it like below, but I would like to do the same with above logic

```
if(i != 0) {
    printf("%d", i);
} else {
    printf("%s", "");

}
```

Comment: Also, read about the way *types* work in [tag:c]. You can't pass two different types to `printf()` with the same specifier because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: The `else` clause in the second snippet does nothing, and can be removed.

Answer (score 8):

Specify a precision of 0:

```
printf("Number is %.0d\n", i);
```

From the C standard's description of the `d` format code, emphasis added (§7.21.6.3):

> The `int` argument shall be converted to a signed decimal in the style "[-]dddd". The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it shall be expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. **The result of converting zero with an explicit precision of zero shall be no characters.**

This feature of `printf` is occasionally useful, particularly when producing tabular output in which you want `0` entries to not be printed. A format code such as `%8.0d` will right-justify an integer value in an 8-character field, printing eight spaces if the value is 0. (The field width is applied to the converted value.)

Comment: This is not correct as `number is ` will be displayed

Comment: @EdHeal : The op might wish to display `number is`.

Comment: @EdHeal: The output is not very clean, but it is what OP asked for.

Comment: @EdHeal You're right, I also provided answer aligned to that Idea, but if you see OP's idea, maybe the `number is` part gets printed always.

Comment: @EdHeal and unclear (after seeing this discussion), too. :)

Comment: @EdHeal: This feature of printf is (1) occasionally useful and (2) apparently not very well known, so I'd say it's a useful question, even though the example is not a particularly useful case.

Comment: The OP also asked for it to be done using the same "_logic_".  I think that means it should be done using the same syntax which would be the ternary operator (the word choice of "logic" is a little unclear, but that would be my take as to what it means)

Comment: @rici: Correction: your answer is useful (and a nice find), but the question is not. You just should have cited the C standard as the more common standard, not POSIX. Not every implementation is POSIX and thre is no indication in the question.

Comment: Re the edit: from the text in the standard(s), It reads as if there is nothing printed, so there will also be no padding to the width. But this might be a defect in the definition.

Comment: @olaf: You have to read the section I excerpted in the context of the entire description. The field width is applied after the value has been converted. (And the C standard has exactly the same words; I actually copied `man sprintf` which on my machine claims to be aligned to Posix. But I fixed the reference in the answer now.)

Comment: @rici: I did not say the C standard differs. Just that your answer invokes the impression it is a POSIX feature. It is in general good practice to use the most basic standard first. So for a C question first check the standard (that's what I did before I commented). Re the field width: Agreed, that seems to be well defined. I'll keep that in mind, if I ever use C on a desktop machine ...

Answer (score 2):

If you *have to* use [conditional statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), you can plan to control the whole `printf()`, based on the value of `i`, like

```
int i=0;
i? printf("Number is %d\n", i): (void)i;
return 0;
```

or, in case, you want the `Number is` to be printed always, use it like

```
int i=0;
i? printf("Number is %d\n", i): puts("Number is");
return 0;
```

Comment: That's a bad idea. Write clear code, `if` is absolutely suitable here.

Comment: @Olaf: It seems, however, that the OP _wants_ to use the conditional statement...The person mentions that he/she is aware of the fact it can be done with an `if` statement.  For whatever reason, it seems the person is inclined to use the ternary operator.

Comment: @iRove108: So there is someone standing with a gun behind him? Maybe I had better teachers, but most were actually open to corrections when they could be proved wrong, even by students. But these were the old days ...

Comment: @Olaf: Fair enough.  Point taken.

Comment: @Olaf That's why I wrote  _have to_ . It is possible with ternary operator, just not the way OP expected.

Comment: @Olaf Also, I agree, this maybe not the _most appropriate_ way to do it, but what is _bad_ about it? Readability? Understandability ?

Comment: Readbility is a necessary requirement to understand code, so - both? :-) The question is nonsense, because no sane person would write "Number is" without an actual number or other text. rici's answer provided a nice usage, but not for this question.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this silly question (might as well throw my hat into the ring)

```
i && printf("Number is %d\n", i);
```

Gets rid of the ternary operator as well!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 30;
    return (i != 0) ? printf("Number is: %d", i) : i;
}
```

Comment: But main will not always return zero

Comment: It seems more useful to return the number of characters printed (if any), zero otherwise. Ofcourse you may say that a non-zero return may indicate an error though... ;)